# Tratando mensagem requisição no Ajax HTTP Status Code

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho uma requisição em Ajax que faz consultada de pagamentos em um servidor de terceiro, gostaria de saber como que faço para tratar erros de HTTP.
Exemplo: *'server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'*
Esse erro pode acontecer por vários motivos, porem só aparece no log, gostaria de tratar e mostra de uma forma elegante para o usuário.

```
 $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                _RecurrentPaymentId = response.Payment.RecurrentPayment.RecurrentPaymentId;
                _NextRecurrency = response.Payment.RecurrentPayment.NextRecurrency;
                _Status = response.Payment.Status;
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `fail` da requisição via AJAX, no seu caso em jQuery.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
 $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                _RecurrentPaymentId = response.Payment.RecurrentPayment.RecurrentPaymentId;
                _NextRecurrency = response.Payment.RecurrentPayment.NextRecurrency;
                _Status = response.Payment.Status;
}).fail(function() {
    alert( "erro" );
});
```

Dentro da função `fail` você pode definir o que deseja que seja feito caso a requisição não tenha sucesso.

Você também pode usar o parâmetro `statusCode` nas configurações do AJAX, que no caso não tenho como saber como estão, pois você atribuiu a variável "settings". Mas você pode adicionar o parâmetro `statusCode` para um determinado retorno HTTP dentro da sua variável settings:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert("página não encontrada");
    }
  }
});
```

Você pode definir uma ação para cada tipo de retorno HTTP.

Documentação oficial do AJAX no jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Olá @Vinicius Gabriel, obrigado por responder. Uma duvida na função `.fail(function()`  consigo pegar o status do erro? Exemplo se é 400, 404 ou 500.

Comment: @mba sim, a função fail() possuí 3 parâmetros de callback que você pode utilizar caos queira (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown). O primeiro objeto que é retornado o 'jqXHR' possui várias propriedades, incluindo o status da requisição. Você pode consulta-la usando jqXHR.status.

Comment: @mba um adendo que não sei que versão do jQuery está usando, mas para poder utilizar essa propriedades precisa está com jQuery 1.5 ou superior.

Comment: entendi. Muito obrigado. Abraços.